# Shadow Effect not working with Resizable NSView

Tags: macos, cocoa

I have written below code for shadow effect for my NSView.

```
    [_nsview setWantsLayer:YES];
    _nsview.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
    _nsview.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
    _nsview.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(.3f, -.3f);
    _nsview.layer.shadowRadius = 10;
    _nsview.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.20; 
    _nsview.layer.shadowColor = [NSColor blackColor].CGColor;
```

_nsview is outlet of that NSView. Above code works perfectly and gives shadow effect...But problem is that after resizing _nsview shadow getting hide.

[image: This is after running my sample app, shadow effect working perfectly]

[image: This is after resizing main window of sample app(_nsview has auto layout constraints, due to that it will also resize with main window)]

Answer (score 2):

Use NSShadow instead:

```
    [_childView setWantsLayer:YES];
    _childView.layer.backgroundColor = [NSColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    _childView.layer.cornerRadius = 5;

    NSShadow *dropShadow = [[NSShadow alloc] init];
    [dropShadow setShadowColor:[NSColor colorWithWhite:0.1 alpha:0.6]];
    [dropShadow setShadowOffset:NSMakeSize(0, -5)];
    [dropShadow setShadowBlurRadius:5];
    _childView.shadow = dropShadow;
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're using a layer-hosting view (note: different from a layer-backed view) then you should assume that `NSView` can change layer properties at any time behind the scenes. Shadows and transforms are the most common properties to change outside of the developer's control.

Here is some useful reading:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/SettingUpLayerObjects/SettingUpLayerObjects.html

https://www.objc.io/issues/14-mac/appkit-for-uikit-developers/